# Modification of objectname of model in yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have a model **Skill.php**. In **SkillController.php ** i have actionCreate method generated by crud

```
actionCreate(){
   $model=new Skill;
       }
```

when i change $model to $modelSkill it showing me error.why?

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Skill;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Skill']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Skill'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->skill_id));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
```

After changing to $modelSkill

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $modelSkill=new Skill;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($modelSkill);

        if(isset($_POST['Skill']))
        {
            $modelSkill->attributes=$_POST['Skill'];
            if($modelSkill->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$modelSkill->skill_id));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$modelSkill,
        ));
    }
```

Comment: because you use $model more than once, i think.
Please post the whole actionCreate.

Comment: i replace all $model with $modelskill

Comment: can you post your error?

Comment: And can you also post your code with the replaced model?

Comment: Undefined variable: modelSkill

Comment: in which file is this error? in the controller or in the view?

Comment: This was on create.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think I found your fail. Can it be that you also replaced it in your View files? if yes, you also need to change this:

```
$this->render('create',array(
    'model'=>$modelSkill,
));
```

to this:

```
$this->render('create',array(
    'modelSkill'=>$modelSkill,
));
```

As you can see in the [Yii documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#render-detail) the array is going to be putted into the function [extract()](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/function.extract.php).